# Can't sharing video from camera roll

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an application which collects the video assets of a users camera roll, using the `Photos` Framework and methods `requestImage` & `requestAVAsset`

I'm allowing the user to share the asset using the `UIActivityViewController` class and the URL from the `AVAsset`. My problem is that for some strange reason it won't allow me to share the video.

On the app the error message I get on the `UIActivityViewController` is

> The item cannot be shared. Please select a different item.

Any pointers or advise is appreciated, thanks!

Here is how I present the `UIActivityViewController`:

```
let selectedVideo = self.selectedVideo //(AVAsset)
let videoURLPath = selectedVideo.url // URL

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let activityItems: [Any] = [videoURLPath]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop, UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,]

    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.frame

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here's how the video URL looks:

> file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/107APPLE/IMG_7966.MP4

Comment: Show the code for how are you presenting `UIActivityViewController`. Also please let us know on which social network you're trying to share the video and video is a normal video or it is recorded as slow motion video?

Comment: please share your code. another problem is if you have linked your iTunes account for storage optimization in your phone then you can't share videos as they need to download from iCloud first.

Comment: @TheTiger I've now added in the code, the video's I target are boomerang videos and mostly have a duration of 3.55, no slow motion.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I've just shared my code. Also my videos aren't on iCloud they're on my device but that's a great point.

Comment: @TheTiger I'm attempting to share to Whatsapp.

Comment: @FuadAdetoro Have you checked the size of that video? It should not be exceed than what whatsapp allows.

Comment: @TheTiger I can't imagine that it exceeds what whatsapp allows as the video is only for 3.55 seconds.

Comment: @FuadAdetoro Oh I read it like 3:55 I was not expecting the time with a dot. Anyway checking on your issue.

Comment: @FuadAdetoro Did you try sharing on any other social network? It might be a issue with whats app too. Also please share the code how are you getting `AVAsset`, share the log of `asset.url`.

Comment: Please have a look in these URLs 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603921/this-item-cannot-be-shared-please-select-a-different-item-whatsapp-ios-share . 2.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423821/whatsapp-showing-alert-this-item-cannot-be-shared-please-select-a-different-it . 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713717/this-item-cannot-be-shared-please-select-a-different-item-sharing-a-simple-te .  Might be issue with whatsapp https://github.com/jberlana/JBWhatsAppActivity

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I've managed to fix this issue now!

Comment: @FuadAdetoro What was the issue?